# Error page not working on production mode on Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, fetch-api

I am developing an application with Nuxt in which I consume an API with dynamic query parameters.

The website where the application is deployed only contains the query parameters if it is opened from another application.

I want to redirect to an error page if the site url does not contain the query parameters to generate the json that the application consumes.

I dont't undestand why the error page works as intended in development mode, but when I use the app in production mode the error page is not displayed.

Am i missing something? or is there a better way to redirect to an error page if the API does not contain the query parameters?

this is my index.vue from where I do the fetch to the dynamic API:

```js
async created() {
    // GET request using fetch with async/await
    
    let uuidBooking = this.$route.query.uuidBooking;
    let nombreCliente = this.$route.query.nombreCliente;

      const response = await fetch(
      `https://e7pmpg7z85.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/obtienedatosbooking?uuidBooking=${uuidBooking}&nombreCliente=${nombreCliente}`
    )

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log((JSON.parse(data.JsonBooking)));
    this.bookingData = JSON.parse(data.JsonBooking);
    
    if (response.uuidBooking === this.$route.query.uuidBooking && response.nombreCliente === this.$route.query.nombreCliente) {
      this.response = response
    } else {
      // set status code on server and
      if (process.server) {
        this.$nuxt.context.response.statusCode = 404
      }
      // use throw new Error()
      throw new Error('Booking not found')
      // this.$nuxt.error({ message: 'Error test'})
    }
  },
```

I have also tried this with try and catch on the index.vue:

```js
async created() {
    // GET request using fetch with async/await
    
    let uuidBooking = this.$route.query.uuidBooking;
    let nombreCliente = this.$route.query.nombreCliente;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
      `https://e7pmpg7z85.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/obtienedatosbooking?uuidBooking=${uuidBooking}&nombreCliente=${nombreCliente}`
    )

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log((JSON.parse(data.JsonBooking)));
    this.bookingData = JSON.parse(data.JsonBooking);

    } catch (error) {
      context.error(error)
    }
}
```

this is my error page:

```html
<template>
  <b-container class="error-container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="text-center p-3">
      <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
      <h1 v-else>We couldn't find any information for this request.</h1>
      <a href="mailto:help@exikhan.com.mx" class="email-link">Get in touch: help@exikhan.com.mx</a>
      <!-- <NuxtLink to="/">Home page</NuxtLink> -->
    </div>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["error"],
  // layout: "blog", // you can set a custom layout for the error page
};
</script>
```

Comment: What is your deployment target? As far as I know development mode in nuxt runs as a nodejs server so it runs your project as a server-side rendered app. But if your target is static then I think  (process.server)  won't work on production.

Comment: Hi @bar5um, the deployment target is server, on production and on development mode is rendering as a server side.

Comment: Please try async fetch() instead of async created()